# iOS Cannot access internet

Tags: ios, reachability

I am checking whether my app have internet access. Strangely, on some device, I can have access to internet. But, it is not okay for some device. Is my coding correct?

If so, is it because of cellular data? It is only happening for my application and all other app seem to be okay. In cellular setting, it allow to use my app with cellular data also.

```
+ (BOOL)isHostReachable:(NSString *)host {
    if (!host || ![host length]) {
    return NO;
    }

    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability =  SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, [host UTF8String]);
    BOOL gotFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);

    CFRelease(reachability);

    if (!gotFlags) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self isReachableWithoutRequiringConnection:flags];
}

+ (BOOL)isReachableWithoutRequiringConnection:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags
{
    // kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable indicates that the specified nodename or address can
// be reached using the current network configuration.
BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable;

// This flag indicates that the specified nodename or address can
// be reached using the current network configuration, but a
// connection must first be established.
//
// If the flag is false, we don't have a connection. But because CFNetwork
// automatically attempts to bring up a WWAN connection, if the WWAN reachability
// flag is present, a connection is not required.
    BOOL noConnectionRequired = !(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired);
        if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN)) {
        noConnectionRequired = YES;
    }

    return (isReachable && noConnectionRequired) ? YES : NO;
}
```

Comment: App Transport Security related? What devices can't access Internet? In which case? Narrowing the devices could be helpful. 3G? Access has been disabled by user in Settings.app ?

Comment: Yes. It is on 3G, ios 9+, iphone 6 and App Transport Security should be okay because I already allow for that.

Comment: App Transport Security has _nothing whatsoever_ to do with reachability. It can only possibly kick in once you _have_ internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that some devices cannot access the Internet. WiFi turned off, 3G turned off, Airplane mode, bad connection, router unplugged. Or it's an iPad without any 3G. All possible.

Once your application is working, you'll need to do some serious testing what happens when Internet gets turned on and off. For example, what happens when you walk away from your office and your WiFi disappears. Or you walk through a shopping centre and various WiFis come and go. Or the user changes settings. Your app should survive anything.

Comment: My phone is on 3G though. And other app on my device is okay. Only my app can't access to internet. Is it because some setting in device? Or DNS?

Comment: Is there any difference if I use www.google.com or http:www.google.com ? To check whether I have internet with Reachability library?